# Creating prevalence map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I work with infectious disease. Right now i want to create a map showing a prevalence of infected people during an outbreak of the disease. 
So I have coordinate data of infected/uninfected people live in the outbreak area. 
Because the study area is a small village, there's no big road or boundary that we can use to calculate prevalence. So i created a grid of X/Y : 0.002 (i think it's 200 meter). Then I count GPS point of  infected/uninfected using point in polygon option in QGIS. Then I calculate prevalence in the grid (Infected/total population). 
So in the end i get the prevalence in each grid but when i shown in the map. it's not very good because the prevalence showing as square shape.

So i come up with another solution which i'm not sure it's right or not. I created center of each grid and the center contain Prevalence value. I then make interpolation with those center. So now i can escape the square issue but because the interpolation use center point to interpolate, the prevalence shown is not 100% correct to the real location of the infected people.

Is there anyone have any suggestion for me. I'm still in the very beginning level of these mapping stuff.

I want my map to look like this:

[image]